# maven surefire plugin - org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I was working on a project for quite some time and everything went fine including the compile, however from yesterday iam getting SurefireBooterForkException

Following are the versions i use

maven-surefire-plugin version is 3.1.2
OpenJDK 17

Below is the stack trace :

```
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
[ERROR] There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:628)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:285)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:250)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1203)
```

your insight on this is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Show your pom file also the full logging output of the error ... also I suppose there is a test failure?